# can I put all my classes in one file using mvc?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am attempting to learn MVC, and I have what is probably a very basic question.  When I am creating classes and objects, can I put all of those in one file like I do with JavaScript?  Or do I need to make a separate file for each class and constructor?
I have looked at a lot of examples on here, but nothing seems very definite to me.

Comment: You **are** allows to put multiple classes in a single file if you wish. Typically in most MVC patterns I've seen each class is separated.

Comment: Separate files is just better for readability, it will be much easier to maintain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't *need* to use separate files for each class, but it's good practice to do so. It's much easier to work with many, smaller files instead of a couple incredibly large files. It'll also make life easier for any other developers that need to work on the project.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the MVC pattern follows the basic rules set for OOP overall: one class = one file.

There might be exceptions to this rule, depending on the framework or CMS you might be using, but placing more than one (unrelated) class in a file tends to complicate the project.

It might be ok to combine several related classes into one file, but I'd still advise against that.

Answer (score -1):

One of the benefits of using separate files that has not already been mentioned is that you can use the [`__autoload()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) function to only load classes as-needed and decrease the overhead required to load your application.

Why load an entire monolithic file or, directory of files, with dozens of class definition if only a handful are required for one particular execution?

This is what I use in my global include file:

```
define('__SITE_PATH', '/path/to/app');
/* auto load model classes */
function __autoload($class_name) {
    $filename = 'class.' . strtolower($class_name) . '.php';
    $file = __SITE_PATH . '/_model/' . $filename;
    if( file_exists($file) == false ) {
        return false;
    }
    require($file);
}
```